# I want to display the message “no result found” when the query returns no result

Tags: php

I am using the following code to search in the site..I wish to display the message "no result found" when the query returns no result.What changings should i do in the code

My Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"]))
{
$user = $_REQUEST["user"];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("iata");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE airportcode LIKE '$user'");
$rowcount=mysql_num_rows($query);
?>

<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>City Name</td>
<td>3 Letter City Code</td>
<td>Airport Name</td>
<td>3 Letter Airport Code</td>
</tr>

<?php
for($i=1;$i<=$rowcount;$i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["cityname"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["citycode"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["airportname"] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["airportcode"] ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
}
?>

</table>


<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: So you want to do something `if( $rowcount == 0)`? What's so hard about that?

Comment: I would also suggest updating to PHP7, to make sure you're taking advantage of all the newest fixes and updates.

Answer (score 0):

You already uses the rowcount. Just check if the count is equal to 0 and you'll know if you have results or not.

More importantly, you are using mysql_* functions. It's advised to use mysqli_* functions instead for almost a decade, they are deprecated since PHP5.5 and have been removed since PHP7.0.

You should use mysqli_* function, or even better PDO :

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=iata', 'root, '');
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM code WHERE airportcode LIKE ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($user));
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        // Your code here
    }
    $db = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error !: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

**Don't touch code with mysql_* functions in it, don't write it, don't copy it, don't give it to anyone, don't even poke it with a stick ! These functions are vulnerable and would render as vulnerable any application that relies on them !**

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
if ($rowcount == 0) {
  $message = "No Result";
}
```

Now you can echo `$message` anywhere on the page to display the message.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your code where you want the message to appear:

```
if ($rowcount == 0) {
  echo 'result set is = 0';
}
```

Comment: Whats with the downvote and no comment?  How does this not return the desired result?